# Batch file to open program and login loses focus when running on startup

Tags: batch-file

trying to get a batch file to run consistently but having issues.

It works perfectly if i run the batch file by double clicking on it.

It works 1 in 5 times if I put it in startup.

It works 2 in 5 times if i use task scheduler and make it a starup taks with a 1 minute delay on starting but it just not reliable.

This issue is:
I need to open a specific program, then enter a username and password to the popup window the program provides at login.

If i run the batch it works, keeps focus and logs in.  If it runs itself at startup, it sometimes loses focus on the login window so the sendkeys doesnt work.

Ive tried everything I know, googled the shit out of it and stuck... looking for a guru who can help PLEASE!!!

**** Note, the dim object shell was the last thing Ive tried adding, It works perfectly removed ;-)

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

set "username=UNAME"
set "password=PWORD"

start /MAX /B "" C:\"Program Files (x86)\MYPROGRAM\THEPROGRAM"\PROGF.exe

timeout /t 30 /nobreak >nul

Dim ObjShell :Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ObjShell.AppActivate("PROGF.exe")

CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%username%{tab}%password%{enter}"

goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Have tried it as a .bat and .cmd files...

Answer (score 0):

The rules are simple on who can successfully call `SetForegroundWindow` the API function `AppActivate` uses.

**You must meet one of the following conditions**

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A
>   process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The process is being debugged.
> - The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start    Screen.
> - The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see       SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> - No menus are    active.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So, can I do this in a batch file or is it only in C++?

Comment: The above isn't batch file but a hybrid mess. To rules apply to every program. Your program will work if written sensibly. You create a process called CScript. CScript has two seconds to make a window or set a window active. As you can see sometimes it makes it, sometimes not. TaskScheduler is not the foreground window and programs it starts can't force the foreground window.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. if I new how to write it correctly, wouldnt be asking for help..

Comment: We don't do program design here, we help with coding errors. Also as you are breaching normal program rules, common for Sys Admin scripts, it's hard to predict. Is PROGF console or GUI? Also SendKeys is inherently unreliable.